# PHP MongoDB, update document without erasing the rest

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a mongo document, using PHP and the update() function. However, when I do this, it replaces the WHOLE document with the value I wanted to update. How can I fix this?

The code I have written up to now: http://twaddlr.com/view/73
(Scroll down to the "update" function. It's a database wrapper I'm writting for my site)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The key is to use `$set` in the update, e.g. instead of this (sorry using JavaScript syntax here, not sure about the exact PHP driver syntax):

```
db.my_collection.update({hello: "world"}, {foo: "bar"})
```

you do

```
db.my_collection.update({hello: "world"}, {$set: {foo: "bar"}})
```

If you use `$set`, only the properties you specify will be updated, the whole document will not be replaced.

You can read more about this in the documentation, here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations

Edit: looking at your code, this is exactly what you do in the `addRow` method. Just do the same thing in `update`.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine. How would I go with making an "addRow" function then? I don't want to replace in that case; I want to add a row (like... if I had a comments or posts array)

Comment: Use `insert` and not `update`. `insert` is for adding, `update` is for updating.